# SEO - Will this url rewriting index particular image?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, google-image-search, google-index

Example, if I have URL to particular image like (which doesn't exist on server):

> domain.com/news/12/imgname.jpg

and i need to generate it on the fly and display it to the end user, i'll use some htaccess to rewrite previous url to:

> domain.com/image.php?img=12/imgname

**My question is:** Will image `imgname.jpg` be indexed by the search engines (image.php in this case will return always the same image generated on the fly)?

Comment: Are you rewriting or redirecting? Do you want it to be indexed or not? The robots.txt file can stop it being indexed, if that is what you want.

Comment: I'm rewriting. I want generated image indexed, but not saved on server :)

Comment: If you are rewriting then everything is internal to your webserver, and the image will be indexed by the same criteria the search engine would use for any image.